# Unity Visual Studio 2017 Freeze and Crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I work with Unity, and recently I came across some sort of bug with Visual Studio. For some reason one day the Script Editor stopped working.

When I first open it up through Unity, it would open as usual and seem fine, but after 5 seconds of interaction, Visual Studio would then freeze and crash without an error report. Following tries with the editor would just crash almost right away.

I did some research and found out that it was some sort of problem with Unity's MEF Cache, the Microsoft Documentation would ask me to do the following: Delete the following file: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<version>\ComponentModelCache" and if the problem continues, I should run this line of code on VS' CMD as a administrator "devenv /setup".

I tried both methods with Visual Studio, but neither seemed to work, only to return to being fine for 5 seconds before freezing and crashing.

I have updated Visual Studio 2017 to the newer version and performed the same method, but the problem persists.

I would like to know if anyone have any solutions to my situation, if I should try reinstalling Visual Studio, try to reinstall Unity or just use another Script Editor.

edit: Just to inform, the version of Unity I was using was 2021.2.8f1. But I don't know if it matters since the bug didn't seem to depend on the Unity version.

Comment: hi, perhaps try reinstalling the app to the latest patch version

Comment: Could I install a different newer version of VS, like a 2020 version and see if that works?

Comment: @NowhereStudio Might be helpful for future travelers to note which version of Unity you were running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by installing Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 0):

With me the problem was gone when i disabled the MySQL extension in Visual Studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).